# Change search select parameters from OR to AND

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch, select

First of all, I've tried to add the ajax search to my website but I didn't like it at all. So my intention is to modify the default search select in a way I like.

What I'd like to do is to change the select parameter which shows you different written words, one OR the other to one AND the other. So there won't be a black T-shirt shown when looking for black glasses, for example.

Do anyone know where is it where I can change the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it by my own.

It is located at /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php. You only need to modify the line 331 and 355 (magento 1.8)

Change those `' OR '` to `' AND '` and it's done.